# Issue with "width" while applying through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container DIV which has 7(this is variable number)DIVs aligned as 7 columns. Since the number of columns are varying, I would like to take the column count and using a jquery calculation(100/column count) and apply this width to each column.For each column separation, I have applied 2px border right for columns except for the last column.I have also applied border-box sizing to avoid the conflicts between percentage width and pixel width border.

My issue is when apply column width through jquery width,

```
var count = $('.col').length;
$('.col').width(100/count+'%');
```

it seems for the first 6 columns it is applying a width of '16.2857%' and for the last column it is '14.2857%'. Actually 14.2857 is the right value to be applied. The border and box-sizing properties affect it.

But on the same time, if you change jquery width to css it works perfectly fine.

```
var count = $('.col').length;
$('.col').css('width',100/count+'%');
```

Any body know why is this happening?

below is my working sample

```js
$(window).ready(function(){

  //This make the width Issue
  var count = $('.col').length;
  $('.col').width(100/count+'%');
  
  //But This works perfectly fine
  //var count = $('.col').length;
  //$('.col').css('width',100/count+'%');
});
```

```css
.container{
  width: 210px;
  height:120px;
  float: left;
  border: solid 2px red;
}
.col{
  height: 100%;
  float:left;
  background:green;
  border-right: solid 2px yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.col:last-child{
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

> Note that .width() will always return the content width, regardless of the value of the CSS box-sizing property. As of jQuery 1.8, this may require retrieving the CSS width plus box-sizing property and then subtracting any potential border and padding on each element when the element has box-sizing: border-box. To avoid this penalty, use .css( "width" ) rather than .width().

Though the preferred way is with `.css()`, you can still get the expected result by using `outerWidth()` instead of `width()`:

```js
$(window).ready(function(){

  //This make the width Issue
  var count = $('.col').length;
  $('.col').outerWidth(100/count+'%');
  //But This works perfectly fine
  //var count = $('.col').length;
  //$('.col').css('width',100/count+'%');
});
```

```css
.container{
  width: 210px;
  height:120px;
  float: left;
  border: solid 2px red;
}
.col{
  height: 100%;
  float:left;
  background:green;
  border-right: solid 2px yellow;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.col:last-child{
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this has something to do with this line from the jQuery docs

> Note that .width() will always return the content width, regardless of
>   the value of the CSS box-sizing property. As of jQuery 1.8, this may
>   require retrieving the CSS width plus box-sizing property and then
>   subtracting any potential border and padding on each element when the
>   element has box-sizing: border-box. To avoid this penalty, use .css(
>   "width" ) rather than .width()

https://api.jquery.com/width/